# View availability message on summary page Cart

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I want to display the availability message on the basket summary page.

In a normal product page the code {$product.availability_message} works just fine, and the message changes depending on availability.

But if i use {$product.availability_message} in cart-detailed-product-line.tpl it displays the same message no matter if the product is in stock or not.

Anyone know how to achieve this in Prestashop 1.7x ? I have searched online for hours without any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{$availability_message} show the message when the product in stock if not you have to use {$product.available_later} so to work fine with that if product in stock show {$product.availability_message} if not show {$product.available_later} like that :

```
{if $product.availability == 'available'}
 {$product.availability_message}
{else}
 {$product.available_later}
{/if}
```

OR : 
`{if $product.stock_quantity > 0 } {$product.availability_message} {else} {$product.available_later} {/if}`

Comment: It works, and it doesent. So the {$product.available_later} prints the right string - so thats good. But the check {if $product.availability == 'available'} returns "available" for all produducts, even several of them have a stock value of 0. So the check on "product.availability" os not the right approach. We need a check on stock level > 0, but how can we do this?

Comment: hello again to check the stock level use `$product.stock_quantity` so your code will be like that                                                                                                  `{if $product.stock_quantity > 0 }
 {$product.availability_message}
{else}
 {$product.available_later}
{/if}` i edit the answer

Comment: Someone know how to edit this "availability_message" variable ?

Comment: the availability_message  is edited in the back office in product page u can edited for each product